# how to make a button on xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting a trouble in designing a button on Xcode.

I am using following code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRect];
button.frame=CGRectMake(80.0,210,160,40);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

the code is Build Successfully. but this  error is coming :

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0xbf7ffffdc)

Comment: Enable breakpoint and find where exactly it is crashing.

Comment: apart from the RoundedRect typo there is nothing wrong with this code, the error is being caused elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can create a customized button as per your required background and text color.

```
 btn_fbLogin = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95,254,130,41)];
[btn_fbLogin setTitle:@"FLogin" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_fbLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(FacebookLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn_fbLogin setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
btn_fbLogin.clipsToBounds = YES;
btn_fbLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
[btn_fbLogin setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:244/255.0  green:185/255.0 blue:25/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_fbLogin setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];     
[self.view addSubview:btn_fbLogin];
```

And don't forget to import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0,210,160,40);
[button setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Error which you are getting is doesn't seem to be coming cause of UIButton. Can you specify more ?